# Traverse upwards in JSON when mapping using RestKit 0.20

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "category": "MyCategory"
  "objects": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "A" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "B" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "C" }
  ]
}
```

I'm mapping each object to a separate Core Data entity like this:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"id" ];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"name": @"name" }];
```

**How do I configure the mapping to store their shared category on each object?**

The thing I would like is to be able to traverse upwards in the JSON like this:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"name": @"name", @"PARENT.category": @"category" }];
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: I don't understand how the link is helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now (RestKit 0.20.1), there is no way to do this by using the mapping engine.

**FUTURE**

There is a new metadata feature under development making it possible to access the parent object:

`[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"name": @"name", @"@metadata.parentObject.category": @"category" }];`

**PRESENT**

I'm modifying my deserialized response using `willMapDeserializedResponseBlock`. I've added a category on RKObjectManager to make it easy to modify the response:

https://gist.github.com/gunnarblom/5677324